# определение кодировки по переданному char* через WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, кодировка

Подскажите, можно ли через WinApi определить кодировку переданной строки char* ? Мне нужно по переданной строке сравнивать является и она Utf8 или же нет.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [MultiByteToWideChar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar):

```
auto const is_utf8
{
  (nullptr != psz_input)
  and
  (
    ('\0' == psz_input[0])
    or
    (0 != ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, psz_input, -1, nullptr, 0)
  )
};
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, а подскажите еще через какую функцию WinApi можно конвертировать в Utf8 кириллицу ? Если можно то с примером.

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar, UTF-8 это один из способов кодирования и кирилицы в том числе. Возможно вы хотите получить строку char* в кодировке CP-1251?

Comment: @ffk Благодарю за отклик, уже решил вопрос несколько иначе.